# Converting molecular structure from Avogadro into LAMMPS coordinate file

Tags: lammps, avogadro

I am new to LAMMPS and have been working my way through available examples before diving into my own research using LAAMPS. I am currently working through the tutorial given here: https://avogadro.cc/docs/extensions/lammps-input-for-water/ . I see that this question has been [asked here before](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/how-to-convert-a-molecular-structure-made-in-avogadro-to-a-lammps-coordinate-fil), but the post was abandoned by the user so there was no indication as to whether or not they sorted out their problem, and if so how. There was also a post on an Avogadro forum [that asked the same question](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/t/avogadro-and-lammps/423), but there were no responses given.

I am having the same issue as this other user. That is, I am able to get to the point where I have to save the structure file in a LAMMPS readable format, but my computer tells me that water.lmpdat is not a valid file name. Saving the .lmp file did work, but this is the input script and not the coordinate data file for the water box.

For reference, I am running Windows 10, and have Avogadro version 1.2.0 installed onto my computer. I have tried using other file extensions like .dat, .data, .in, and .input and I am given the same "File name is not valid error". I have also tried independently generating the coordinate data file and am met with formatting errors, so I would like to try this approach again to see if it works this time. Any insight on this matter is welcome, and if there is any other information I should provide, let me know in a reply/comment and I will provide what I can.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! Please see [this](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/423/5) though.

Comment: FYI - the post you linked on the Avogadro forum was from 2015 .. we responded via e-mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion, frankly, is to use a newer version of Avogadro. The [betas of Avogadro2](https://two.avogadro.cc/) include a much more substantial LAMMPS input generator. This includes generating both the input and the `lmpdat` file.

On the downside, I haven't had much help updating the user documentation for Avo2, so help is definitely appreciated. Feedback is, as always, welcome on our forum: https://discuss.avogadro.cc/

[image]

Comment: Ah ok. Admittedly I was not aware of a newer version of Avogadro. I'll install it and try, and will report back if everything works out alright

Comment: Everything works just fine, thanks!